# What are the limitations of apportable Indie version ?

Tags: android, ios, apportable

I have `apportable` starter version, I want to buy indie version ,so want to know every thing about limitations and drawbacks of indie version.
Like can we build unlimited apk for a month, support inapp purchase,ads etc.

second thing I want to know that I have installed starter so how can I update to indie.

I know its silly questions but I am new to `apportable` and I want to know quickly as possible..
thanks.....

Comment: have you tried [looking at their website?](http://www.apportable.com/pricing) That would be the first stop for information about them.

Comment: thanks for quick reply panini, yes read all this things but i want all in detail thats why i am asking

Comment: Are they still active? It seems like they have stopped working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding there are none.

Enterprise version just gets you better support and it looks like feature development, which ties into better support.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

They have a page on their website that deals exactly with this:
http://www.apportable.com/pricing

From my experience (I have the Indie version), until now, I had absolutely no limitation in terms of porting, even with 3rd party libraries, APIs and SDKs. We haven't officially launched our first Apportable ported game, but I'll get back when we do, and modify with relevant data ASAP.

Comment: will you please provide us the Apportable SDK version which you are currently using ? I also have upgraded apportable to Indie version but it is not able to compile ChartBoost SDK.